# How to make HOME, END to work on terminal without X

Tags: zsh

my current keys config is:

```
typeset -A key

key[Home]=${terminfo[khome]}
key[End]=${terminfo[kend]}
key[Insert]=${terminfo[kich1]}
key[Delete]=${terminfo[kdch1]}
key[Up]=${terminfo[kcuu1]}
key[Down]=${terminfo[kcud1]}
key[Left]=${terminfo[kcub1]}
key[Right]=${terminfo[kcuf1]}
key[PageUp]=${terminfo[kpp]}
key[PageDown]=${terminfo[knp]}

# setup key accordingly
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-of-line
[[ -n "${key[End]}"     ]]  && bindkey  "${key[End]}"     end-of-line
[[ -n "${key[Insert]}"  ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Insert]}"  overwrite-mode
[[ -n "${key[Delete]}"  ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Delete]}"  delete-char
[[ -n "${key[Up]}"      ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Up]}"      up-line-or-history
[[ -n "${key[Down]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Down]}"    down-line-or-history
[[ -n "${key[Left]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Left]}"    backward-char
[[ -n "${key[Right]}"   ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Right]}"   forward-char

# Finally, make sure the terminal is in application mode, when zle is
# active. Only then are the values from $terminfo valid.
function zle-line-init () {
    echoti smkx
}
function zle-line-finish () {
    echoti rmkx
}

if [ -n "${DISPLAY:-}" ]; then
   zle -N zle-line-init
   zle -N zle-line-finish
fi
```

completion and other zsh files here: https://github.com/Cynede/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh/config.sh

The trouble is that this `bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-of-line` doesn't work for terminal with no Xorg running seems like. It pastes `~` on both `HOME` and `END`. How can I make it to work without Xorg too?

Comment: What do you see when you type Ctrl-V, Home? See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.unix.shell/PjuDehtFhM8/eerjOqAWwxoJ)

Comment: what I see is `^[[1~`

Comment: What about `print -r -- ${(V)terminfo[khome]}`?

Comment: what I see is `^[OH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$terminfo` special parameter in zsh is filled from data that comes from the terminfo database on your system.

In your case, it seems that the entry in the database for the terminal you're using is incorrect.

The terminfo database is indexed on the value of the `$TERM` environment variable.

So either `$TERM` is incorrect or the database is incorrect.

What terminal is that? Is that the console of some BSD operating system? What does `$TERM` contain? Are you logged in locally or logging in to some remote system (which may have a different terminfo database) over ssh/rsh?

Comment: True, I were setting wrong TERM right in zsh. Thank you.

Comment: @Heather. OK. I realise I read the comments backward and would now bet that you're on the Linux console and had TERM set to `xterm`. Note that you should **not** set `$TERM`, it should be set by automatically by the terminal emulator or `getty` (and transfered automatically via ssh/rlogin/rsh). The only time when you might need to change it is if you're rlogging-in to a system that has different settings for a given entry.